# Oracle XMLType mapping with entity object in Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

A SQL table has a column of type XMLType. Having structure as below:-

```
<values>
 <value lang="EN">Mozilla loran lipsum</value>
 <value lang="ZH_CN">Bugzilla 绕过安全限制安全漏洞</value>
 <value lang="ZH_TW">Bugzilla 操控安全性避開弱點</value>
 <value lang="KO">Mozilla 조작 보안 우회 취약점 </value>
 <value lang="JA">Bugzilla 操作におけるセキュリティ回避の脆弱性 </value>
</values>
```

I am trying to map this column with JPA entity field.

I want this XML data in HashMap as `Map<String, String>` and the entry will be
`Key :- Language`
`Value :- Text`

Is there any way to transform the XMLType into HashMap with above requirement.